# Как правильно оформить импорт множества модулей на python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, импорт, pep8

Вот [здесь](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html) я прочитал, что когда импортируешь модули, каждый импорт нужно располагать на отдельной строчке. То есть нельзя писать

```
import os, sys
```

а нужно

```
import os
import sys
```

У меня возник следующий вопрос. Я пишу большую программу, в которой используется 11 стандартных модулей Python. И что же мне — ради улучшения читабельности каждый импорт располагать на отдельной строчке?

Comment: А почему бы и нет?:) У меня 16 импортов на 16 строках в коде))

Comment: Но согласен, чуток неудобно

Comment: @ЧёткаяЧетырка, да, я в исходниках некоторых встроенных модулей питона видел, как они этим правилом пренебрегают и импортируют несколько модулей одной строчкой.

Comment: +, то же самое)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете создать `__init__` файл, в котором прописать все импорты.

****init.py****

```
import os
import sys
```

**main.py**

```
from __init__ import *

print(os.__doc__)
print(sys.__doc__)
```

[Подробнее в документации](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)